# Redirect entire subdirectory to a domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an entire subdirectory to our main domain.

Basically links like this:

- `https://garrysun.com/dev/ayurveda-products/categories/ayurvedic-ghee-clarified-butter?limit=15`
- `https://garrysun.com/dev/`
- `https://garrysun.com/dev/ayurveda-products/`

Should all go to

`https://garrysun.com/`

We are using OpenCart 2.3.0.2

I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://garrysun.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ https://garrysun.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

But neither seems to work. What is the best .htaccess rule to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/dev/.htaccess` have this single rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?garrysun\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://garrysun.com/? [R=301,L]
```

---

Your web server appears to be Nginx as per the response headers. For Nginx use this rule:

```
location ~ ^/dev/ {
    return 301 https://garrysun.com/?;
}
```

Comment: So I have nothing in the dev folder other than the .htaccess file with only the lines you show above. If I go to https://garrysun.com/dev/ it redirects me to the main site but if I go to another page I get a 404 error: https://garrysun.com/dev/ayurveda-products/

Comment: sorry, I tried something else that caused the 403 error. Now it is 404.

Comment: Could it be cause it is trying to go to the web root rather than https://garrysun.com

Comment: I get 403 on https://garrysun.com/dev/ and 404 on https://garrysun.com/dev/ayurveda-products/

Comment: Response headers show `server: nginx/1.12.2` and I am still getting 403 for `https://garrysun.com/dev/` which means above .htaccess is not even read.

Comment: If that is the case how can I redirect if the server is nginx?

Comment: Here it says the server is apache: https://garrysun.com/dev/phpinfo.php why would the headers show different? In my hosting company cpanel it shows apache also.

Comment: I did get a 500 error when adding random text to the .htaccess file. So if that means that it is enabled why is it not redirecting? I switched it back to only the 5 lines that you gave me and it give me a 403 error again.

Comment: If that rule is working with Apache then `https://garrysun.com/dev/phpinfo.php` will also be redirected to new domain

Answer (score 0):

I used this redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that if the page doesn't exist in the main website I get a 404 error.

For example:
This: https://garrysun.com/dev/777-oil-psoriasis
Becomes this: https://garrysun.com/777-oil-psoriasis
I get a 404 error because that page doesn't exist on the main site.

This works:
https://garrysun.com/dev/ayurveda-products/
Becomes:
https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/
because the new site has that page.